# Syntax error at or near "EXCEPTION"

Tags: postgresql, exception, syntax-error, postgresql-8.4

Could anybody tell me where possibly can I have syntax error in trigger procedure below?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hd.insert_insteadof_update()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
 BEGIN                                         

   IF (OLD <> NEW)                               
   THEN
     NEW.set_date = now();         

     INSERT INTO hd.ticket_attachment              
     VALUES (NEW.*);

   EXCEPTION WHEN UNIQUE_VIOLATION THEN END;  
   END IF;      

   RETURN NULL;  

 END;   
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

I use PostgreSQL 8.4.

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EXCEPTION" LINE 13:    EXCEPTION WHEN
>   UNIQUE_VIOLATION THEN END;
>               ^
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "EXCEPTION" SQL state: 42601 Character:
>   356

Comment: You are missing a `begin` For an example see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING

Comment: yes, it works, thank you. I haven't used an extra begin with exception before...